# One-hot vectors encoding with NetEncoder

Tags: vector, neural-networks, character-encoding

I have a text and vocabulary (text has two `"the"` entries):

```
list = {"the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"}
voc =  {"the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "lazy", "dog"}
```

And I can do integer codes with `NetEncoder`.

```
NetEncoder[{"Tokens", voc}][list]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {1}, {7}, {8}}
> ```

But for `NetEncoder["Tokens"]` documentation states the following:

> "Tokens"  -> encode tokens in a string as a sequence of integer codes **or one-hot vectors**

What is the correct way to implement **one-hot vectors**? (I'm on WM 11.3)

---

**P.S.** One may do one-hot vectors encoding manually, but I need the way compatible with `NetTrain` functionality:

```
Thread[voc -> IdentityMatrix[Length[voc]]]
```

> {"the" -> {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>        "quick" -> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>        "brown" -> {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>        "fox" -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>        "jumps" -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
>        "over" -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
>        "lazy" -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
>        "dog" -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ["Class" `NetEncoder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/netencoder/Class.html) outputs one-hot vectors when the `"UnitVector" form` is specified:

```
NetEncoder[{"Class", voc, "UnitVector"}][list]
```

> {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
>
> {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
>
> {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}